# set 3 corresponding points on rectangle based on given one

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

Idea is very simple, imagine that you have any rectangle and you want to roll random point on its border, i have accomplished that by doing this:

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 200,
    margin = 0;

var rnd = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(max) - Math.ceil(min) + 1)) + Math.ceil(min);
};

var point = rnd(0, (width * 2) + (height * 2));

var points = [
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 0, y: 0 }
]

var set_point = function(point) {
    var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
 
    if(point <= width) { // if on top
        coords.x = point;
        coords.y = -margin;
    } else if(point <= width + height) { // if on the right
        coords.x = width + margin;
        coords.y = point - width;
    } else if(point <= (width * 2) + height) { // if on the bottom
        coords.x = ((width * 2) + height) - point;
        coords.y = height + margin;
    } else { // if on the left
        coords.x = -margin;
        coords.y = ((width * 2) + (height * 2)) - point;
    }
 
    return coords;
};

var test = set_point(point);
points[0].x = test.x;
points[0].y = test.y;

for(var i = 0; i < 1 /*points.length*/; i++) {
 var dot = document.createElement('div');
 dot.className = 'point';
 dot.style.left = points[i].x + 'px';
 dot.style.top = points[i].y + 'px';
 document.querySelector('.rect').appendChild(dot);
}
```

```css
.rect {
    border:solid 1px #000;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(50% - 100px);
    left:calc(50% - 150px);
}

.point {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:solid 1px red;
    background:red;
    transform:translate3d(-5px, -5px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

So now when i have a random point an a rectangle i need to also assign 3 remaining corresponding points like this:

[image]

I tried to do this using couple of approaches but none of them seem to work correctly, does anyone have an idea how to get remaining 3 points based on one that i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a random number between 0 and `Math.min(width, height)`. Let's call this random number `d`. From there, the coordinates of your points within the rectangle are as follows:

- `d, 0`
- `width, d`
- `width - d, height`
- `0, height - d`

You just need to apply this principle to your implementation.

Comment: But suppose the width was ten times the height. Then your 'random' point on the horizonal would always be close to the edge.

Comment: If the points need to be equal distance from the corners, then this problem is inherent to the question.